# function is not defined at HTMLImageElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, ajax

this is my php function which i am calling from my html page,

```
public function uploadfile(){
        $imageData = '';
        if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'][0])) {
            foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $keys => $values) {
                $fileName = uniqid() . '_' . $_FILES['file']['name'][$keys];
                array_push($_SESSION['kycfiles'],$fileName);
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$keys],  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '\application\files\new\\' . $fileName)) {
                    $imageData .= '<div class="img-wrap">
                                        <img src="'.base_url().'/application/files/new/' . $fileName . '" class="thumbnail"  onclick="removeFormData(`'.$fileName.'`)"/>
                                        <label class="remove-image" onclick="removeFormData(`'.$fileName.'`)" style="display: inline;">&#215;</label>
                                    </div>';
                }
            }
        }
        echo $imageData;
    }
```

now when i click on lable, it calls removeFormData function, there i am getting this error
*view:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: removeFormData is not defined
at HTMLImageElement.onclick*

what i am trying to do is, upon calling this removeFormData function, this will call another ajax that will remove the image from the array and show the remaining images.

i am also looking for some suggestion about how to add event listener if that is an option.

here is my removeFormData function which is defined in that html page

```
function removeFormData(filename) {
          $(".loading")
            .removeClass("d-none")
            .addClass("d-block");
        
            let filedata = { 
                 'filename' :   filename
             }
          $.ajax({
            url: "<?php base_url(); ?>/upload/removeuploadedfile",
            method: "POST",
            data: filedata,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
              $(".loading")
                .removeClass("d-block")
                .addClass("d-none");
              $("#showThumb").html(data);
            }
          });
        }
```

Comment: Did you define the `removeFormData()` function? Is it in the global scope?

Comment: @Barmar yes i already defined that.

Comment: Apparently not, or you wouldn't be getting that error. I suspect it's not in the global scope, maybe it's inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Also it is spelled `label`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to clean up your code so you don't have to deal with inline click handlers, you can always delegate the click to the document. And just have the file as a data attribute on the parent.

Also, in ajax you can pass context:$(this) and it will allow you to pass the calling this instead of the success' this. Then in your success just remove the object from the DOM, you don't need to reload it every time.

```js
$.fn.removeFormData = function(){
  const filename = $(this).data("file");
  
$(".loading")
            .removeClass("d-none")
            .addClass("d-block");
        
            let filedata = { 
                 'filename' :   filename
             }
          $.ajax({
            url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
            method: "POST",
            data: filedata,
            context:$(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
              $(".loading")
                .removeClass("d-block")
                .addClass("d-none");
              $(this).remove();
            }
          });
  
}

$(document).on("click",".img-wrap",function(){
  $(this).removeFormData();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-file="theFiile1" class="img-wrap">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/EEE/31343C" class="thumbnail" />
  <label class="remove-image"style="display: inline;">&#215;</label>
</div>

<div data-file="theFiile2" class="img-wrap">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/EEE/31343C" class="thumbnail" />
  <label class="remove-image"style="display: inline;">&#215;</label>
</div>

<div data-file="theFiile3" class="img-wrap">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/EEE/31343C" class="thumbnail" />
  <label class="remove-image"style="display: inline;">&#215;</label>
</div>
```